# Typescript angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am programming an angularjs application in visual studio using typescript. I want to include the ngImgCrop module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-crop-full-extended) into my application but have not been successful at doing so. Here's how I tried to include the module in my component

```
import {ngImgCrop} from 'ng-img-crop-full-extended'
```

I already installed the package using

```
npm install ng-img-crop-full-extended
```

inside my angular application directory and included the required reference to

```
ng-img-crop.js and ng-img-crop.css
```

scripts in my index.html. The javascript version requires me just to include the module like this

```
angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop'])
```

However, I have no idea on how to include it into my version of angularJs using typescript. Any help will be great thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? You are describing something that should work.

Comment: sorry for being vague, I am not able to include the ngImgCrop module in my typescript application, whenever I call the `<img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>` directive, my angular app does not render, it compiles but does not render in the browser, so I have no error message to report

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a Javascript import which does not actually inject the `ngImgCrop` module into your AngularJS project.
You still have to include the module in your app's AngularJS module as you mentioned above using the following code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop']);
```

(This assumes you want to name your application's module `app`.)

The other javascript import you are doing, ie the `import {ngImgCrop} from 'ng-img-crop-full-extended`, can be used to import the Typescript classes so they can be used in the vscode intellisense, but it is not actually used by the AngularJS framework at all. If the ngImgComp code isn't a Typescript file then there is no need to import it using the javascript import at all.

If you want the intellisense for the ngImgCrop code, you can see if there is a Definitely Typed file for ngImgCrop and install that using

```
npm install @types/<ngImgCrop project name>
```

Then include the `index.d.ts` file from that installed project in the `build.imports.d.ts` file for your project by adding the following line, replacing ngImgCrop with the correct name.

```
 /// <reference path="mode_modules/@types/<ngImgCrop project name>/index.d.ts />
```